# Angular two way binding from HTML input type=date to Date object in model

Tags: angular

In Angular I have HTML (which I get from Matt Lewis Angular calendar):

```
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let event of events">
      <td>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          [(ngModel)]="event.title"
          (keyup)="refresh.next()"
        />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input
          class="form-control"
          type="date"
          [(ngModel)]="event.end"
          (ngModelChange)="refresh.next()"

          placeholder="Not set"
        />
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteEvent(event)">
          Delete
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

And I have a class:

```
export interface CalendarEvent<MetaType = any> {
    id?: string | number;
    start: Date;
    end?: Date;
    title: string;
    color?: EventColor;
    actions?: EventAction[];
    allDay?: boolean;
    cssClass?: string;
    resizable?: {
        beforeStart?: boolean;
        afterEnd?: boolean;
    };
    draggable?: boolean;
    meta?: MetaType;
}
```

The problem is with binding from   `[(ngModel)]="event.end"` to interface `CalendarEvent` field `end?: Date;`

It is simply doesn't work, not propagating to event value:

```
dex.js:47 Starting with v2.0.0-beta.1 date-fns doesn't accept strings as date arguments. Please use `parseISO` to parse strings.
```

I try to separate

```
      <td>
        <input
          class="form-control"
          type="date"
          [ngModel]="event.start"
          (ngModelChange)="event.start = $event"

          placeholder="Not set"
        />
      </td>
```

But I don't exactly know if is correct way and if I should implement any method in `.ts` file.

How to do this kind of mapping in Angular?